# Are there different cuts of the ferry scene in "The Dark Knight"?

Tags: alternate-version, the-dark-knight

I just watched "The Dark Knight" again, after having seen it just once before at the cinema in 2008. One of the scenes that stuck with me was the ferry scene.

A ferry full of prisoners and a ferry full of other citizens are jammed by the Joker during the crossing. The Joker uses loudspeakers to tell the passengers on both boats that they have a detonator to blow up the other boat. If none of the boats is blown up by a certain time, he will detonate both boats.

> On the prisoners' ferry, one of them throws the detonator overboard. Meanwhile the non-prisoners hold a vote in which they decide to blow up the other ferry, but no one has the courage to press the detonator. The only one who wants to take matters into his own hands silently puts down the detonator at the last moment. The Joker is overwhelmed by Batman. None of the ferries is shown exploding.

But I remember the scene very differently.

> One of the non-prisoners activates the detonator, but the Joker lied to them all. The detonator does not blow up the other ferry, but the one it is on. The prisoners watch in astonishment as the ferry with the non-prisoners blows up.

I am completely surprised that the scene was missing, but I can find no evidence online that it existed as I remember it.

Are there different cuts of the movie? Or is this my most severe case of false memories?

Comment: Would kind of go against the movie's theme and Batman's proving that the citizens of Gotham are worth saving etc etc.

Comment: It seems, I'm not alone though: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69521/what-did-the-jokers-detonators-actually-target?rq=1#comment111808_69521

Comment: I remember when watching that scene for the first time; I was guessing / predicting that it would happen as you remember. I’m sure other people thought so to: so the false memory could be a result of thinking about what you thought would happen when watching it.

Comment: Perhaps it's a comic-book plot that played out different in print than on screen

Comment: AFAIR, neither prisoners nor the citizens blew up, prisone's detonator was thrown out by one of the prisoners and nobody had the courage to press it in the citizen's side.

Comment: I asked the other question. I don't remember the ferry actually exploding, but the gag of the detonator targeting the same boat was on my mind a couple of years ago. Maybe someone will find something new this time around, but I think it is just false memories :/

Comment: I would call this the most severe case of Mandela effect ever.:)

Answer (score 1):

It never happened in the Batman movie, but a ferry *did* explode in the movie [*Deja Vu* (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453467/).  It's very possible that it's a false memory triggered by this movie.

I actually Googled® "ferry explodes movie" and Deja Vu is the only result to show up on the first 2 pages.